# selenium proxy SSL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time

options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://id:pw@ip:port',
        'https': 'https://id:pw@ip:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.myip.com/')

time.sleep(100)

driver.quit()
```

```
ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for www.google-analytics.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found
```

I'd like to know the code that makes SSL (https) authentication work. I bought a paid proxy.

I'm making a traffic bot.